# jQuery ComponentsKnobDials on change events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using this jQuery plugin:

http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

How do i:

1. Get the value of the knob
2. Adjust the value using jQuery
3. Setup onChange listeners

My current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $(".bulb").click(function() {
        $knob = $(this).prev().children()[1];

        if ($knob.value > 0) {
            $knob.value = 0;
        } else {
            $knob.value=100;
        }
    });

});
```

The problem is, the input value gets updated, but the indicator does not change.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

@chuckfinley I put this demo together in case someone in the future runs into this problem as well. In your specific case you can change the `on` listener to `click`. Hope this helps!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Knob Stackoverflow Demo</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="http://anthonyterrien.com/js/jquery.knob.js"></script>
        <script>


            //THE BELOW SCRIPT HANDLES THE CHANGING OF KNOB VALUE 
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#input').bind('input',  function() { //THIS LISTENS FOR A CHANGE IN THE input TEXT BOX
                var t = $('#input').val();
                    $(".knob").val(t).trigger('change');
                });

            //INITIALIZE KNOB FUNCTIONALITY
            $(".knob").knob({  });
            });
        </script>

        <style>
            body {margin: 0 auto; width:1000px;}
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <form>
            Knob Value: <input type="input" id="input">

        </form> 
        <br>
        <div id='kb'>
            <input class="knob" data-width="150" data-cursor=true data-fgColor="#FF0000" data-thickness=.3 value="29">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```